# MYSQL- match against boolean mode does not return anything for exact words like "first", "last"

Tags: mysql

Here is an example -

SELECT `title`, `desc` FROM `stories` WHERE MATCH (`title`,`desc`) AGAINST ('"last"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

There are records in the stories table that contain exact word 'last' but this query does not retun those records.

It matches any other words but not these -'first', 'second', 'last' etc

Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because those are stopwords which are so common that are *ignored* by full-text search. You can look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html for the full list of stopwords.